# How do you reference and execute chutzpah.console.exe installed via nuget in your gulpfile

Tags: angularjs, gulp, jasmine, nuget, chutzpah

Given you have installed chutzpah for a solution via:

nuget install-package chutzpah for a given project.

and you have installed jasmine via:
npm install --save-dev jasmine

and you want to use gulp-chutzpah to execute jasmine tests.

how do you reference the chutzpah.console.exe that was installed through nuget to:   (some relative path)\packages\Chutzpah.4.3.4\tools\chutzpah.console.exe

so that you may execute the corresponding gulp task with:

gulp runChutzpahTests

Comment: not sure what the continuous integration story is going to look like for this...but nuget install chutzpah installs the chutzpah executable to the tools folders.  the npm installs are already available to the package manager console path...so executing gulp from the package manager console works well locally.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have written a function that just scans the packages folder and finds the latest version of the Chutzpah package and chooses that exe.